# linked list segmentation fault c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

So im creating a program with multiple linked lists and when creating a new node on a linked list it has a segmentation fault.

Here is an example on how im defining a list and how i create a node

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class node_A
{
public:
    string nameA;
    unsigned int codeA;

    node_A* nextA;
};


class list_A
{
private:
    node_A* headA;

public:
    list_A()
    {
        headA=NULL;
    }
    ~list_A()
    {
            node_A *current, *nextA;
            current=headA;
            while(current!=NULL)
            {
                nextA=current->nextA;
                delete current;
                current=nextA;
            }
    }
    unsigned int lastNodesCode()
    {
        node_A *current=headA;
       if(headA==NULL)
       {
           return 0;
       }
       else
        {
            while(current!=NULL)
            {
                if(current->nextA==NULL)
                {
                    return current->codeA;
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current->nextA;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void newNodeA()
    {
        node_A *newNode=new node_A;
        node_A *current;
        string nameA;

        newNode->codeA=lastNodesCode()+1;

        cout<<"Name A: ";
        getline(cin,nameA);
        newNode->nameA = nameA;



        newNode->nextA=NULL;
        if(headA==NULL)
        {
        headA=newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            current=headA;
            while(current->nextA!=NULL)
                current=current->nextA;
            current->nextA=newNode;
        }
    }


};

class node_B
{
public:
    string nameB;
    unsigned int codeB;

    node_B* nextB;
};


class list_B
{
private:
    node_B* headB;

public:
    list_B()
    {
        headB=NULL;
    }
    ~list_B()
    {
            node_B *current, *nextB;
            current=headB;
            while(current!=NULL)
            {
                nextB=current->nextB;
                delete current;
                current=nextB;
            }
    }
    unsigned int lastNodesCodeB()
    {
        node_B *current=headB;
       if(headB==NULL)
       {
           return 0;
       }
       else
        {
            while(current!=NULL)
            {
                if(current->nextB==NULL)
                {
                    return current->codeB;
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current->nextB;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void newNodeB()
    {
        node_B *newNode=new node_B;
        node_B *current;
        string nameB;

        newNode->codeB=lastNodesCodeB()+1;

        cout<<"Name B: ";
        getline(cin,nameB);
        newNode->nameB = nameB;



        newNode->nextB=NULL;
        if(headB==NULL)
        {
        headB=newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            current=headB;
            while(current->nextB!=NULL)
                current=current->nextB;
            current->nextB=newNode;
        }
    }


};


int main()
{
    list_A A;
    list_B B;

    A.newNodeA();
    A.newNodeA();


    B.newNodeB();
    B.newNodeB();
}
```

In my code when i try to add a new node in a linked list thats not the first it has a segmentation fault.
But in this example its not having that problem, i cant post my entire code here because its to big, i have 8 linked lists

Comment: *i have 8 linked lists* -- Why do you have 8 separate linked-list classes?   You're supposed to create one class, and just declare 8 variables of that type, no?

Comment: The type of data in each list varies alot, I need to use multiples lists

Comment: No, `list_A` and `list_B` are identical as far as I can see. If you need different data types, that's what templates are for.

Comment: That was just for the example, in my program, that consists of managing a market, so I have a list for the products, one for the type of products, on for each sale etc

Comment: For an example you duplicate the code? Really? Templates will be your friend. And for the purpose of asking about a segmentation fault, I'm pretty sure seing everything once will be enough ;)

Comment: You don't need to define multiple lists.  As the comment suggested, that is what templates are for.  If you create *one* linked list class, rename all of those custom node types to `T`, then create a simple template based on `T`.  It is insanity to create `n` linked list classes because you have `n` different types.

Comment: In addition to what was mentioned, why is `main` dealing with nodes?  Isn't all that work supposed be the linked list's job?  A linked list class would have a simple `add()` function, where `main` just calls `list.add(whatever)`, and the linked-list class figures out how to deal with nodes.  The `node` is a detail of the linked list class, and shouldn't need to be exposed to `main`.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie isn't that what I have done in my main?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error? I tried linked list list_A and its working fine. Can you mention the details of error in question?

Comment: I can't replicate in a code small enough to post here, I don't know how to explain

Comment: @josilva00 -- Why are there input routines in the middle of your linked list class?   That is not how you build such a class.  [Look at this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4421facc7ffceb7).  That is in a nutshell what would be expected of a class that takes any type, and how such a class should be tested.  Note that all that needs to be changed is the type, i.e.`list_A<int>`, and the class should work for `int`.  Change to `list_A<double>`, and it will work with, `double`, etc. Not an umpteen different list classes...

Comment: @josilva00 _"I can't replicate in a code small enough to post here"_ - does this mean the code you posted now does _not_ replicate the problem? Then you need to look for the problem yourself. But this code is basically the same code twice. If the problem occurs here it will occur, when you take one duplicate away.